# JSoup - Select Images not inside a link

Tags: java, html, css-selectors, jsoup

How can I select all images that are not inside of a link element?

```
document.select("a img"); //selects all images inside a link
document.select(":not(a) img"); //images not inside a link (does not work)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so the problem here is that `:not(a) img` needs just one element around the `<img>` which is not an `<a>` containing an `<img>`. For example `<body>` matches for `:not(a)`. So your selector matches nearly all `<img>` tags. Even if you pass an HTML string to `Jsoup.parse()` which doesn't have a `<body>` or `<html>` tag. Jsoup automatically generates it.

Let's assume we have the following HTML:

```html
<html>
  <body>
    <a><div><img id="a-div-img"></div></a>
    <a><img id="a-img"></a>
    <img id="img">
  </body>
</html>
```

If you just want to exclude direct `<img>` childs in `<a>` you can use `:not(a) > img` as selector:

```java
Elements images = document.select(":not(a) > img");
```

The result will be this:

```html
<img id="a-div-img">
<img id="img">
```

The problem with this is that it also prints the first `<img>` of the example, which is actually inside an `<a>` (`#a-div-img`). If this in enough to fit your needs you can go with this solution.

Excluding all `<a>` tags from the selection is not possible with a pure CSS (at least I didn't find a solution yet). But you can just remove all `<a>` tags from the document before selecting all `<img>` tags:

```java
document.select("a").remove();
Elements images = document.select("img");
```

The result will be just this:

```html
<img id="img">
```

If you need the original document without modifications you can use `Document.clone()` before:

```java
Document tempDocument = document.clone();
tempDocument.select("a").remove();
Elements images = tempDocument.select("img");
```

Using this the original document is never modified.